# TextInput suddenly stopped working in Kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, textinput

I am building a simple Kivy app with a couple of screens. The first screen has a couple of buttons which, when clicked, move to the second screen. The second screen has a text input widget and a button inside a Float Layout. The layout is loaded as a root widget by an explicit call to the kv file through Builder.

Everything was working fine and I added a 'focus: True' tag in the text input attributes. The app worked fine and I could type in the text input field with focus set as True. However, the text input field suddenly stopped working without any change in code or layout. I was not sure and searched Google for a couple of probable solutions, none of which worked:

1. Removed the 'focus: True' attribute and reloaded the app but the text input field still did not respond. I was unable to type anything from my keyboard.
2. Another post pointed out that the kv file was being loaded twice resulting in erratic behaviour. I tried to remove the explicit Builder file call and returned the root widget (Screen Manager) in the main code. However, it messed up my entire app and only showed a black empty screen.

Can you please advise as to what I may be doing wrong? The code is provided below:

**Python Code:**

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','sivaicon.png')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class SivaLoginScreen(Screen):
    def twitter_authentication(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.current='verify_screen'

    def linkedin_authentication(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.current='verify_screen'


class SivaVerifyScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SivaTabbedScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SivaScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


# Tell Kivy to directly load a file. If this file defines a root widget, it will be returned by the method.
root_widget = Builder.load_file('siva.kv')

class SivaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Initialize root widget
        return root_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run application
    SivaApp().run()
```

**kv file:**

```
SivaScreenManager:
    SivaLoginScreen:
    SivaVerifyScreen:
    SivaTabbedScreen:


<ImageButton>:
    keep_ratio: True


<SivaLoginScreen>:
    name: 'login_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 195/255, 60/255, 35/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Image:
            id: login_logo_siva
            source: 'images/sivalogo1.png'
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.75}
        Label:
            id: login_label_siva
            pos: self.x*0.5-4, self.y*0.5+15
            markup: True
            font_name: 'roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf'
            text: '[color=#FDFD98]S.[/color][color=#B29DD9]I[/color][color=#FDFD98].[/color][color=#77DD77]V[/color][color=#FDFD98].[/color][color=#779ECB]A[/color]'
            font_size: '40sp'
        Label:
            id: login_label_slogan1
            pos: self.x*0.5-3, self.y*0.5-6
            markup: True
            font_name: 'roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
            text: '[color=#FDFD98]SLOGAN TEXT[/color]'
            font_size: '13sp'
        Label:
            id: login_label_slogan2
            pos: self.x*0.5-3, self.y*0.5-20
            markup: True
            font_name: 'roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
            text: '[color=#FDFD98]HEADLINE TEXT[/color]'
            font_size: '13sp'
        BoxLayout:
            id:login_button_layout
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.25}
            ImageButton:
                id: twitter_button
                source: {'normal': 'images/twitter-96.png', 'down': 'images/twitter-96.png'} [self.state]
                on_release: root.twitter_authentication()
            ImageButton:
                id: linkedin_button
                source: {'normal': 'images/linkedin-96.png', 'down': 'images/linkedin-96.png'} [self.state]
                on_release: root.linkedin_authentication()


<SivaVerifyScreen>:
    name: 'verify_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 195/255, 60/255, 35/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            id: verify_label
            markup: True
            font_name: 'roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
            text: 'Paste the verification code'
            font_size: '16sp'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
        TextInput:
            id: verify_input
            multiline: False
            font_size: '30sp'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.55}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        ImageButton:
            id: verify_button
            source: {'normal': 'images/lock-96.png', 'down': 'images/lock-96.png'} [self.state]
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.35}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5


<SivaTabbedScreen>:
    name: 'tabbed_screen'
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            pos: self.x*0.5, self.y*0.5
            text: 'SECOND SCREEN'
            font_size: '50sp'
```

Please advise. I am helplessly stuck. :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this was the problem: Some of my widgets were overlapping each other thereby rendering the widgets underneath as unresponsive. In my case, a button widget was overlapping my textinput widget due to which I was unable to enter text in the textinput widget.

I used the Kivy inspector tool to identify the extent of the widgets' dimensions:

```
python3 main.py -m inspector
```

Use Ctrl+e to launch the inspector while the app is running and click on each widget to check its size, position and parent. I reduced the button widget's size and converted the float layout into a stacked box layout and this resolved the issue.